# How to use 2 variables in a for loop for 2 separate arrays?

Tags: bash

Thanks for your help.
I what to run a for loop that queries 2 arrays on an Ubuntu machine:

```
for ((prod in "${Prod_elements[@]}";sProd in "${Prod_elements_stripped[@]}"))
```

the arrays listed above are created when running the for in bash and are not files

```
Prod_elements=("a/A" "b/B" "c/C" "d/D" )
Prod_elements_stripped=("a-A" "b-B" "c-C" "d-D")
```

then

```
do echo "$prod" " " "$sProd"
done
```

so

in completeness
Prod_elements=("a/A" "b/B" "c/C" "d/D" )
Prod_elements_stripped=("a-A" "b-B" "c-C" "d-D")

```
for ((prod in "${Prod_elements[@]}";sProd in "${Prod_elements_stripped[@]}"))
do 
echo "$prod" " " "$sProd"
done
```

It gives the error arithmetic exp wanted.
How would I go about this?
Thanks

Comment: You know you can trivially convert `a/A` to `a-A`? So if the values in your arrays are just a simple substitution of `/` to `-` then you don't need two arrays

Comment: Similar: [How to iterate a command with two different variables?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/386492) or [Unix Script, problem with a 2d array](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/487603)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am guessing what you want to do correctly, you can use a single associative array instead of two indexed arrays:

```bsh
declare -A prod=( ["a/A"]="a-A" ["b/B"]="b-B" ["c/C"]="c-C" ["d/D"]="d-D" )
for key in "${!prod[@]}"; do
  printf "Key '%s' corresponds to value '%s'\n" "$key" "${prod[$key]}"
done
```

If you *must* use the approach you were considering, you can do it by iterating using an index:

```bsh
Prod_elements=("a/A" "b/B" "c/C" "d/D" )
Prod_elements_stripped=("a-A" "b-B" "c-C" "d-D")

for ((i=0; i<${#Prod_elements[@]}; i++)); do
  printf '%s %s => %s\n' "$i" "${Prod_elements[$i]}" "${Prod_elements_stripped[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: BRILLIANT ! Thank you so much! Both work, one is more elegant than the other.